# Android -- Displaying HorizontalScrollView of WebViews

Tags: android, listview, webview, scrollview

So, the idea is to be able to view a very simple html page (text and one image) that can scroll vertically and place this view in a horizontal list that scrolls and snaps to the closest html page.

I've read over and over that, for performance reasons, it isn't a good idea to place web/scroll views inside list views.  I'm trying to avoid writing a new view from scratch but am lost as to what direction I should go.

Answer (score 1):

To get the snapping to occur, you may want to consider using a [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html). It essentially works the same as the list view but is horizontal.

To avoid using a webview, consider using the [Html.fromSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20android.text.Html.ImageGetter,%20android.text.Html.TagHandler)) function. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758535/display-images-on-android-using-textview-and-html-imagegetter-asynchronously) for details.